# Login to asp.net mvc site from php site

Tags: php, asp.net, ajax

I have a login form in php site. When user fill the form and submit, form is submitted via ajax (jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit) to asp.net site and redirected to member area of the asp.net site. These two sites are on different domains. Can I make the user login to asp.net site this way from php site? I own both sites so I can modify both sites if necessary. I am using ajax because login form is in a jquery popup and I need to show login errors in the popup (for look and feel consistency). Thanks

Comment: If the login causes a redirect anyway, why use AJAX at all?  A standard form POST would be a lot easier.

Comment: @David Yes I can do that, but I need to show login error messages etc. to user as the login form is in a jquery popup in php site. That's why I am using ajax

Comment: I'm guessing that you are facing a problem with crossdomain policys. There are a few options to resolve this. Use JSONP, Allow crossdomain on the asp.net site, in the web.config or encapsulate the ajax call. Instead of calling directly to the asp.net site. Call to a php on your same domain via ajax, and that php make a serverside request to the asp.net site to get the posibles errors.

Comment: Wonder why someone has down voted my question... :)

Comment: @Asela you're welcome, tell me if it works (or not)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using cookies, the only way the end-user can be issued with the correct cookie for site B is if they visit site B. So you could do...

- Site A takes credentials
- Site A passes credentials to B
- Site B authenticates and gives a url back to site A
- Site A redirects the user to the url
- Site B uses the url to issue a cookie to the user

This keeps site A in charge of the authentication but it's needlessly complex and mistakes can result in vulnerabilities.

A better approach would be...

- Site A presents a login form which POSTs to site B
- Site B authenticates and returns a redirect to site A (different urls depending on success)

This way, B is wholly responsible for its own authentication and cookies.